# Passport stamp in return travel from Dubai to India

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, passport-stamps, air-india

I am on short visit to Dubai, and on my return flight I am planning to take the flight from Dubai(DXB) -> Mumbai(BOM) -> Rajkot(RAJ), and the operator will be Air India. My question is where the immigration process / passport stamping will be done ? At Mumbai Airport or At Rajkot Airport ?

Comment: Mumbai, most likely. Since you will need to "immigrate" back into India before taking a domestic flight.

Comment: Rajkot doesn't have any immigration facilities.

Comment: clear mumbai immigration and take a domestic flight to rajkot. what terminals?

Comment: thanks for the comments, do I need to collect the luggage at the Mumbai airport and again check in for the domestic flight ? or just need to complete the immigration ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flights from Dubai to Rajkot on Air India are not 'direct', which means you will exit the plane in Mumbai as usual, enter India/get your passport stamp, and then proceed to wait for the departure of your second flight.

[image]

So the answer is that you will get your stamp in **Mumbai**.

Comment: @JonathaReez thanks for the answer, do I need to collect the luggage at the Mumbai airport and again check in for the domestic flight ? or just need to complete the immigration ?

Comment: @ITppl see [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66491/dubai-mumbai-mangalore-luggage-transfer). Since Rajkot airport doesn't have an international facility you would have to collect your luggage.

Comment: I appriciate your prompt reply sir, what will be the allowed baggage weightage, cause generally on international flight they provide more weightage than domestic in my case it is written as 30 kg, they will allow the same 30 kg during my Mumbai to Rajkot flight ?

Comment: @ITppl yes, since it's a single ticket